# How do I get my code to list index number in my sequences

Tags: python, linux, bioinformatics, gnu, biopython

My code is supposed to find and list the index number of the sequence "ACYT" within a larger sequence input as a fasta file. This is what I have so far, but all is does is print ['AC[CT]T']

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import SeqUtils

fasta = input("Enter Fasta File: ")

sequences = SeqIO.parse(fasta, "fasta")

for record in sequences:
    event = Seq("ACYT")
    results = SeqUtils.nt_search(str(sequences),event)
    print(results)
```

Comment: Can you provide data for us to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Why are you passing `str(sequences)` as a search sequence to search in? The `sequences` object is an iterator and `str` doesn't consume it. Do you want, by any chance, to use `str(record.seq)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to give an index to the result returned from `nt_search`. For example, 1 If you want the first occurrence.

Next, You are supposed to pass a string `record.seq` as a first parameter. I couldn't check exactly for your problem as you haven't provided the data but it works with mine.

```
for record in sequences:
    event = str('A')
    sequence_string = str(record.seq)
    results = SeqUtils.nt_search(str(record.seq), event)[1]
    print(results)
```